# Changing contents of div tag dynamically multiple times

Tags: javascript, html

I have changed the contents of a `div` tag once using

```
document.getElementById("di").innerHTML = content;
```

In the changed content, I have a button which is calling a function, I want that function to change the contents of same `div` tag again to other. I have tried doing same i.e. by using

```
document.getElementById("di").innerHTML = content2;
```

But it is not working. Can it be done using some other way, or what can be wrong in current method?

```
function change(){
    document.getElementById("di").innerHTML = "";
    var content = "<span class='senr'><input type='button' value='sender' onclick='sen()'></input></span>";
    document.getElementById("di").innerHTML = content;
}
function sen(){
    document.getElementById("di").innerHTML = "";
    var content1="<span class='prp'>hello</span>";
    document.getElementById("di").innerHTML = "content1";
}

 <div onclick="change()">welcome to page!</div>
```

Comment: It should work, can you post some of your code?

Comment: if your button has an `onclick` event it is possible that you are not overriding it correctly. Post more code please, or even better, a JSFiddle

Comment: I believe the second function is invoked when button click event. If that so it will work. Can you please paste your code which is making that call?

Comment: As the people above have said, your example above should work (in theory).  Some actual code would help with debugging.

Comment: yeah.. i'v added the code. In function 'sen', if i put alert, alert is shown but contents of div are not altered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/1j01/AXcZx/0/
Note the setting "`No wrap - in <body>`". This is because the onload option wraps the source in a function, making the functions in the source inaccessable from the DOM. You shouldn't put event handlers in attributes.

Here it is with the event handlers defined in the code: http://jsfiddle.net/1j01/AXcZx/1/
This works at the end of the `<body>` or in `onload`. Also, it's a good habbit to store references to elements in variables so you don't have to search the document for them each time.

Answer (score -1):

this is ajax function which is call on button and file name is file with html code which replace this div

```
  function functionname(id){                                                   
        var p_url=filename,
        jQuery.ajax({          
        type: "GET",
           url: p_url,                   
           data: "&id=" +id+',
            success: function(data) {
             jQuery(".classnameoddiv").html(data);
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                  
         });                                                                                                                        
        }
```

Comment: why ajax, why jquery, why make me lose time posting this?

Comment: this is invalid syntax and jquery has a [method](https://api.jquery.com/load/) for that